# Auctex key-bindings for easy saving, compilation and viewing.

Tags: key-bindings, latex

I am new to Auctex and Emacs. Previously I have been using vim-latex in which the key bindings are easy. For example, I was using Ctrl-Space in Vim to to save the tex file, compile the document and view the document and comeback to my tex file again where I left the cursor.  Currently the command for Auctex for compiling and previewing is `C-c C-a`. After entering this command, Emacs asks me to save the file ( I need to enter 'yes'). So this makes a little bit time.

So my question is: How to define  `Crtrl-Space` in Emacs so that it will ease the Auctex to compile,save and view the document?

Comment: From my perspective it is a bad thing to rebind `C-SPC`. That key sequence is globally bound to `set-mark-command` which is needed to select a region with the keyboard. Note, that the `C-c C-a` key sequence of AucTeX is quite sensefully designed. The prefix `C-c` starts major-mode related key sequences and `C-c C-a` is a library binding standing for "all". I would suggest to bind `C-c a` for your special command since that is [one of the key sequences reserved for you as a user](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, perhaps you have already found the answer, if so I hope that you were planning to give it here and mark it ;). If not: the proces with which I would approach such a task is: find out in which keymap the bindings are which are already close to what you want; in this case: `C-c C-a`. Simply ask about them with `C-h k C-c C-a` You'll see it's in `LaTeX-mode-map`.

So now you can do this:

```el
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-SPC")
  (lambda ()
    "Save the buffer and run `TeX-command-run-all`."
    (interactive)
    (save-buffer)
    (TeX-command-run-all nil)))
```

Thanks by the way, I'm an evil user and I hadn't bothered, since the shortcut I had bound as an alternative for `C-c C-a` was pretty convenient already. However not having to bother with pressing `y RET` is definitely an improvement! ;)

[edit]

Tobias' comment below, provides the possibility to also save other documents/files that are part of the Tex master file. If that is what you prefer, use the following binding. There `save-buffer` is replaced by `TeX-save-document`. With the `let`-binding of `TeX-save-query` it saves modified buffers silently if they are part of the master document. If you want to be asked whether these files should be saved or not remove the `let`-binding of `TeX-save-query`.

```el
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-SPC")
  (lambda ()
    "Save the buffer and run `TeX-command-run-all`."
    (interactive)
    (let (TeX-save-query) (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-command-run-all nil)))
```

Comment: `(save-buffer)` is insufficient. Use

`(let (TeX-save-query) (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file)))` instead.

Comment: That is a nice suggestion, thank you! However for me, it's not the behaviour I want. I don't like the command to silently save other documents I may have standing edits in. Perhaps the OP does however, so this suggestion is definitely  valuable. I'll add it as an option to my answer.