# AucTeX: Keybinding for compiling document

Tags: key-bindings, latex, auctex

Is there a command, for which I can set a keybind for compiling the document?  The command (TeX-command-master, bound to C-c C-c) gives you a list of options but it's rather inefficient.  I'm looking for a way to just directly invoke LaTeX.

While searching around, I came across [Auctex key-bindings for easy saving, compilation and viewing.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34967/auctex-key-bindings-for-easy-saving-compilation-and-viewing), however that command also opens the PDF viewer after it is finished compiling, which I do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking an the source for `TeX-command-master`, I think binding this code to a key should do the trick:

```lisp
(TeX-command "LaTeX" 'TeX-master-file)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

The package [czm-tex-compile](https://github.com/ultronozm/czm-tex-compile.el) provides a key-binding that toggles continuous compilation of the document via latexmk.